# Identifying HTML colour codes placed in one pixel

Tags: color, corel-draw, pixel, html

1. How many colours at once can one pixel contain?
2. Is there a tool that can represent this pixel in a form of HTML colour codes? (And if there are many colours in this pixel, can this tool show the order of how colours are distributed all over the pixel - it's like 4 colours in a pixel and it says that colour #NNNNNN is placed first on the left, then second is on the right and so on - or in any other explanation)*

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer: One pixel can contain one color (and one value for opacity, but that's not relevant here). The different letters/number you see in your color code are the values that constitute it.**

HTML colors are defined using a **hexadecimal notation** (HEX), those are the letters/numbers you see, and they are the combination of **Red, Green, and Blue** color values (RGB).

The lowest value that can be given to one of the light sources is 0 (in HEX: 00). The highest value is 255 (in HEX: FF). HEX values are specified as 3 pairs of two-digit numbers, starting with a # sign, the ones you mentioned. These are not 3 different colors in one, but one color made of them (because all colors are combinations of red, green and blue).

[This site will give you a better view](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp), as it shows how colors are constructed in HEX codes.

You can [get the value of any pixel](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-get-the-Hex-code-for-any-color-on-your-scre/) in your photo using for example a color picker in any graphic software (Photoshop, Gimp, etc), and use this code in web. All browsers will understand this HEX language.

If you want to **convert your whole image to HEX**, you can use a converter. I haven't tried any, but if you do a search for "convert image to HEX" you will be able to [find a few](http://www.portablefreeware.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=28022).

Comment: Oh, that's great! I will get back to you sooner or later. I should try some first. Thanks

Comment: Please do, if you find one that is good it might be useful for someone else. The ones I found were more than 10 years old!

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems to be web-focused: you can get a colour picker add-on for most browsers that let you click any pixel and get its colour code right there, including in HTML hex format. **[Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/)** is a longstanding popular choice for [Firefox](http://www.colorzilla.com/firefox/) and [Chrome](http://www.colorzilla.com/chrome/).

*(Internet explorer actually has one built in, believe it or not... `ctrl-k` or `Developer Tools (F12) > Tools > Show Color Picker` brings it up)*

As well as the basics - click any pixel on any web page, and it'll tell you what colour it is - it has a bunch of other handy features including a DOM Color Analyzer that gives you an instant palette of the colours used in text and backgrounds on a page, and a built in [CSS gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). It's one of three web design supporting add-ons I use all the time (alongside [MeasureIt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/measureit/) for measuring pixel dimensions and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)).

Example:

[image]

---

Color analyzer example (results at bottom):

[image]